# how to use a variable as a folder name in path

Tags: php

I'm trying passing variable in path for local folder,but this doesn't work.

$year already defined and have a value  in my code
this give me empty blank.

```
$_txt.= '<a target="_blank" href="\\\172.21.65.27\m\$Year\ ">Open...</a>';
```

Comment: where is your try?

Comment: $_txt.= '<a target="_blank" href="\\\172.21.65.27\m\$Year\ ">Open...</a>';